# Invite command leave discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make an invite command, it's working pretty fine, but I want to include also leaves.
i tried `userInviteCount1 -= invite['leave'];` but it doesn't work, can someone help me ?

Comment: What should `invite['leave']` return? What exactly do you want?

Comment: Example: A user left the server, i want the output to be invites: invites and leaves: leaves take InviteManager as an example.

Comment: Just register an event handler for invites.

Comment: and how do i do that? i'm new in discord.js

Comment: See [this](https://gist.github.com/koad/316b265a91d933fd1b62dddfcc3ff584#file-discordjs-cheatsheet-js-L173)

Comment: I still can't get it ..

Comment: You can use the code in the line marked by the link to execute something whenever a user leaves.